# Python: backtracking permutations issue

Tags: python, permutation, backtracking

I have a problem such that in an arena there are  m lions and n tigers, and I need to find all possible sequences of solutions, in order to take them out in such way that no two tigers are taken out one after another. I need to use a backtracking method. My idea was to generate all possible permutations of the initial list of lions and tigers and to keep only the valid ones. Here is my code, but the problem is that I did not find a way to remove the duplicates from the solution.. Does anyone have any idea how to fix this? Thanks in advance!

```
def toString(List):
    return ' '.join(List)

def is_solution(listOfTL):
    for i in range (0, len(listOfTL)-1):
         if listOfTL[i] == "T" and (listOfTL[i] == listOfTL[i+1]) :
             return -1
    return 0

def permute(a, l, r):
     if  is_solution((a)) == 0 and l == r:
         print (toString(a))
     else:
         for i in range(l,r+1):
             a[l], a[i] = a[i], a[l]
             permute(a, l+1, r)
             a[l], a[i] = a[i], a[l] 

def main():
     n = int(input ("Number of tigers: "))
     m = int(input ("Number of lions: "))
     listOfValues = []
     for i in range (0, n) :
         listOfValues.append('T')
     for i in range (n+1, m+n+1):
         listOfValues.append('L')
     print(permute(listOfValues, 0, len(listOfValues)-1))
```

Comment: This seems like a homework assignment. Check out `itertools` module and report back what you find there. There are source code / links on the doc page too.